# Pattern for formula which contains number, letters ,expressions and brackets

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to write a regular expression for the formula for the following examples.

1. `C=A+B  => Output for match will be {A, +, B}`
2. `D= C+50 => Output for match will be{C, +, 50}`
3. `E = (A+B)*C -100 => Output for match will be{(, A, +, B, ), *, C, -, 100}`

I tried with *regular expression*

```
[A-Z(\d*)*+/-]
```

the output for this is `{A, +, 5, 0}`

But it does not give correct output for `A+50`

Comment: Regular expressions are a poor choice of tool for analysing expressions. There are several other tools and techniques that are much better. You might start by reading the information on the [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parsing/info) tag on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest **FSM** (Finite State Machine) instead of *regular expressions*. We have `3` states here:

1. Neither variable, nor number `0`
2. Within variable              `1`
3. Within number `2`

**Code:**

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string formula) {
  int state = 0;

  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (var c in formula) {
    if (state == 0) { // neither var nor number
      if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        continue;

      if (char.IsDigit(c)) {
        buffer.Append(c);
        state = 2;
      }
      else if (char.IsLetter(c)) {
        buffer.Append(c);
        state = 1;
      } 
      else 
        yield return c.ToString();
    }
    else if (state == 1) { // within variable
      if (char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsLetter(c))
        buffer.Append(c);
      else {
        yield return buffer.ToString();
        buffer.Clear(); 

        state = 0;

        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
          yield return c.ToString();
      }
    }
    else if (state == 2) { // within number
      if (char.IsDigit(c))
        buffer.Append(c);
      else if (char.IsLetter(c)) {
        // 123abc we turn into 123 * abc
        yield return buffer.ToString();
        buffer.Clear();

        state = 1; 

        yield return "*";

        buffer.Append(c);
      }
      else {
        yield return buffer.ToString();
        buffer.Clear();

        state = 0;

        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
          yield return c.ToString();
      } 
    }
  } 

  if (buffer.Length > 0)
    yield return buffer.ToString();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "C=A+B",
    "D= C+50",
    "E = (A+B)*C -100",
  };

  string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => new {
      formula = test,
      parsed = Parse(test)
        .SkipWhile(term => term != "=") // we don't want "C = " or alike part
        .Skip(1)
    })
    .Select(test => $"{test.formula,-20} => {string.Join(", ", test.parsed)}"));

 Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
C=A+B                => A, +, B
D= C+50              => C, +, 50
E = (A+B)*C -100     => (, A, +, B, ), *, C, -, 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `|` (or) for the individual items such as a pattern

`\d+|\W|\w`

which translates to any number(s) OR any non alphabetic character OR any alphabetic character.